# Dont open URL after .click() selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

i am scraping data from a form using selenium and BeautifulSoup. 
First step is submiting entry in a search field. Second step is scraping the data from the newly loaded form. 
Both of these steps are doable.

EDIT:
When the script sends entry (*send_keys()*) and clicks submit button (*submit.click()*) the webapage loads. I want the webpage to load in background so I dont see it.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

searchterm = "DE431311903710"
url = 'http://eagri.cz/public/web/mze/zemedelstvi/zivocisna-vyroba/zivocisne-komodity/kone/centralni-pristupove-misto-pro-evidenci.html'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()#, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)

driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    ## You have to switch to the iframe like so: ##
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

    ## Insert text via xpath ##
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")
elem.send_keys(searchterm)

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"btnVyhledat\"]")

submit.click()

p = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features = "html.parser")
l = []
k = []
inputs = p.find_all('span',{"class":"editprvek"})
inputs2 = p.find_all("span",{"class":"editpopis"})
for i in inputs:
    l.append(i.text)

for j in inputs2:
    k.append(j.text)

def merge(list1,list2):
    merged = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]
    return merged

print(merge(k,l))
```

Comment: What type of pop up? An alert or a new tab/window?

Comment: new tab/window. When you manually open : "http://eagri.cz/public/web/mze/farmar/IZR/centralni-pristupove-misto-pro-evidenci.html" and fill the field UELN (with for example DE431311903710) it reloads. Using the script the same page opens during the run.

Comment: I don't get any pop-up when I search that UELN

Comment: sorry for being unclear, just edited, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem Once you submit the search it takes time to load the table data.

Add this line after `submit.click()` Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".editprvek")))
```

Import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: not quite what i am looking for, just edited the question, hope it helps

Comment: You can't do this on the fly.If you want to hide the browser then you have to do it from beginning using `headless` mode.